# docker rocker rmarkdown::render error pdflatex not found

Tags: docker, r-markdown, pdflatex

I am using rocker to render an rmarkdown pdf on a Mac Version 12.6.1 with Linux.

In bash:

```
cd /Users/user/Documents/Docker_Project/
touch Dockerfile
```

Dockerfile contains:

```
FROM rocker/r-ver:4.2.2
RUN apt-get update \
  && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
   wget \
   graphviz \
   perl && \
   /rocker_scripts/install_pandoc.sh && \
   install2.r rmarkdown
ENV RSTUDIO_PANDOC=/usr/lib/rstudio/bin/pandoc
COPY . /home/user
WORKDIR /home/user/
RUN Rscript -e "rmarkdown::render('Paper.Rmd')"
```

Paper.Rmd contains:

````
---
title: "Factor Analysis"
output: pdf_document
date: "2023-04-04"
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

# Methods

- Sample Text
````

In bash:

```
docker build . -t analysis
```

Produces:

```
 => ERROR [7/7] RUN Rscript -e "rmarkdown::render('Paper.Rmd')"                                                                                                                                       1.9s
------                                                                                                                                                                                                     
 > [7/7] RUN Rscript -e "rmarkdown::render('Paper.Rmd')":                                                                                                                                                  
#11 0.817                                                                                                                                                                                                  
#11 0.817                                                                                                                                                                                                  
#11 0.817 processing file: Paper.Rmd                                                                                                                                                                       
                                                                                                            
#11 1.353 output file: Paper.knit.md
#11 1.353 
#11 1.358 /usr/bin/pandoc +RTS -K512m -RTS Paper.knit.md --to latex --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+tex_math_single_backslash --output Paper.tex --lua-filter /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/rmarkdown/rmarkdown/lua/pagebreak.lua --lua-filter /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/rmarkdown/rmarkdown/lua/latex-div.lua --embed-resources --standalone --highlight-style tango --pdf-engine pdflatex --variable graphics --variable 'geometry:margin=1in' 
#11 1.850 ! sh: 1: pdflatex: not found
#11 1.850 
#11 1.850 Error: LaTeX failed to compile Paper.tex. See https://yihui.org/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips. See Paper.log for more info.
#11 1.850 In addition: Warning message:
#11 1.851 In system2(..., stdout = if (use_file_stdout()) f1 else FALSE, stderr = f2) :
#11 1.851   error in running command
#11 1.852 Execution halted
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c Rscript -e "rmarkdown::render('Paper.Rmd')"]: exit code: 1
```

I have absolutely no idea what the error is and have found no resources on how to fix it. Any help is appreciated. Also very happy to reformat, clarify, or add any necessary information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the solution is to install `texlive-latex-extra` and `lmodern`

Comment: Thank you! I tried it and got a new error that tlmgr user mode is not initiated and "! LaTeX Error: File `lmodern.sty' not found". I'm wondering if there's a larger issue with how I'm interacting with LaTex and pandoc since I had to add this section to avoid pandoc errors in the first place. pandoc, TexLive, LaTex, and everything else is available in my Applications

Comment: Try replacing the package you are installing with texlive-fonts-recommended.  [Here it helped](https://trac.macports.org/ticket/48971)

Comment: Tried that - didn't work. Wondering if I just need to restart and use a multistage approach.

Comment: @LauraJamison. And the error is the same as last time? If so, try adding lmodern in apt-get install

Answer (score 0):

Changed Dockerfile to:

```
FROM rocker/r-ver:4.2.2

RUN Rscript -e "install.packages('lavaan')"

RUN Rscript -e "install.packages('semPlot')"

RUN apt-get update \
  && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    wget \
    graphviz \
    texlive-latex-extra \
    lmodern \
    perl && \
    /rocker_scripts/install_pandoc.sh && \
    install2.r rmarkdown

ENV RSTUDIO_PANDOC=/usr/lib/rstudio/bin/pandoc

COPY . /home/lj5yn
WORKDIR /home/lj5yn/

RUN Rscript -e "rmarkdown::render('Paper.Rmd')"
```